# Integral Iteration $\int_{0}^{2\pi}x^{2m}\cos 2nx dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

everyone.

Calculate $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}x^{2m}\cos 2nx dx~~~$   where $m$,$n$ are positive integers.
Could you tell me the formula and proof ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [See this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae)

Comment: I tried Leibniz theorem but failed.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I did the same and got the same. but, I can't proceed any more. That is, I am finding explicit expression for m,n

Answer (score 2):

I am slightly afraid that the general solution is given by an hypergeometric function
$$I_{m,n}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}x^{2m}\cos (2nx)\, dx=\frac{(2 \pi )^{2 m+1}}{2 m+1}\, _1F_2\left(m+\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2},m+\frac{3}{2};-4 \pi ^2 n^2\right)$$

Here are some values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 m & n &I_{m,n} \\
 1 & 1 & \pi  \\
 1 & 2 & \frac{\pi }{4} \\
 1 & 3 & \frac{\pi }{9} \\
 1 & 4 & \frac{\pi }{16} \\
 1 & 5 & \frac{\pi }{25} \\
 1 & 6 & \frac{\pi }{36} \\
 2 & 1 & -3 \pi +8 \pi ^3 \\
 2 & 2 & -\frac{3 \pi }{16}+2 \pi ^3 \\
 2 & 3 & -\frac{\pi }{27}+\frac{8 \pi ^3}{9} \\
 2 & 4 & -\frac{3 \pi }{256}+\frac{\pi ^3}{2} \\
 2 & 5 & -\frac{3 \pi }{625}+\frac{8 \pi ^3}{25} \\
 2 & 6 & -\frac{\pi }{432}+\frac{2 \pi ^3}{9} \\
 3 & 1 & \frac{45 \pi }{2}-60 \pi ^3+48 \pi ^5 \\
 3 & 2 & \frac{45 \pi }{128}-\frac{15 \pi ^3}{4}+12 \pi ^5 \\
 3 & 3 & \frac{5 \pi }{162}-\frac{20 \pi ^3}{27}+\frac{16 \pi ^5}{3} \\
 3 & 4 & \frac{45 \pi }{8192}-\frac{15 \pi ^3}{64}+3 \pi ^5 \\
 3 & 5 & \frac{9 \pi }{6250}-\frac{12 \pi ^3}{125}+\frac{48 \pi ^5}{25} \\
 3 & 6 & \frac{5 \pi }{10368}-\frac{5 \pi ^3}{108}+\frac{4 \pi ^5}{3} \\
 4 & 1 & -315 \pi +840 \pi ^3-672 \pi ^5+256 \pi ^7 \\
 4 & 2 & -\frac{315 \pi }{256}+\frac{105 \pi ^3}{8}-42 \pi ^5+64 \pi ^7 \\
 4 & 3 & -\frac{35 \pi }{729}+\frac{280 \pi ^3}{243}-\frac{224 \pi
   ^5}{27}+\frac{256 \pi ^7}{9} \\
 4 & 4 & -\frac{315 \pi }{65536}+\frac{105 \pi ^3}{512}-\frac{21 \pi ^5}{8}+16
   \pi ^7 \\
 4 & 5 & -\frac{63 \pi }{78125}+\frac{168 \pi ^3}{3125}-\frac{672 \pi
   ^5}{625}+\frac{256 \pi ^7}{25} \\
 4 & 6 & -\frac{35 \pi }{186624}+\frac{35 \pi ^3}{1944}-\frac{14 \pi
   ^5}{27}+\frac{64 \pi ^7}{9}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$I_m=\int_0^{2\pi} x^{2m}\cos{(2nx)}dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2n}\sin(2nx)x^{2m}\big|_0^{2\pi}-\frac{m}{n}\int_0^{2\pi}x^{2m-1}\sin(2nx)dx$$
$$=\frac{m}{2n^2}(\cos(2nx))x^{2m-1}\big|_0^{2\pi}-\frac{m(2m-1)}{2n^2}I_{m-1}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes, I got the same but ...the  iteration is hard to solve...

Comment: As Claude Leibovici's answer showed, you can't really solve it. You can, however, simplify the cos(2nx) term.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative way involving derivatives. Observe
\begin{align}
\int^{2\pi}_0 x^{2m}\cos(2n x)\ dx =&\  \operatorname{Re}\left(\int^{2\pi}_0x^{2m}e^{i2n x}\ dx \right)= \operatorname{Re}\left(\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{(-1)^m}{4^{m}}\frac{d^{2m}}{ds^{2m}}e^{2 xis}\ dx\bigg|_{s=n} \right)\\
=&\ \frac{(-1)^m}{4^m}\frac{d^{2m}}{ds^{2m}} \operatorname{Re}\left( \int^{2\pi}_0 e^{2xis}\ dx\right)\bigg|_{s=n}\\
=&\ 2\pi\frac{(-1)^m}{4^m}\frac{d^{2m}}{ds^{2m}}\left(\frac{\sin(4\pi s)}{4\pi s}\right) \bigg|_{s=n}.\\ 
\end{align}